# Cutting Diagonal Lines

Tags: modeling

Ok I need to cut two diagonal lines into a plane essentially creating an X. Problem is blender has no easy to use tool for this so I chose to triangulate the plane and this only creates one diagonal line going from the top left vertex to the bottom right how do I make that second diagonal line from the top right to bottom left?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

What you are looking for is the *Poke Faces* operation.

In Edit Mode, with your plane selected, press <kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>P</kbd>. This operation creates a node at the face's center, and then triangulates the face around that central vertex.

Answer (score 5):

You can use **connect vertex path** to create new edges. Select two vertices and press <kbd>J</kbd>:

[image]